# Question about integral closures and localizations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A$ is an integral domain with integral closure $\overline{A}$ (inside its fraction field), $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal of $A$, and $\mathfrak{P}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{P}_k$ are the prime ideals of $\overline{A}$ lying over $\mathfrak{q}$. Show that $\overline{A_\mathfrak{q}} = \bigcap\overline{A}_\mathfrak{P_i}$ (note that the LHS is the integral closure of a localization, whereas the RHS is the intersection of localizations of integral closures of $A$).

If it would help, I suppose we could assume that $A$ has dimension 1, so that $\overline{A}$ is Dedekind, though I don't think that assumption is required.

(Geometrically, we're comparing the integral closure of a local ring at a singular point Q of some variety with the intersection of local rings at points in the normalization mapping to Q).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First notice that without extra hypothesis, the integral closure needs not be finite over $A$, and there might be infinitely many prime ideals lying over a given one in $A$. Nevertheless, the equality holds.

It is easy to see that the LHS is contained in the RHS because the latter is integrally closed and contained in the field of fractions of $A_q$. Let $f$ be an element of the RHS (possibly infinite intersection). Denote by $B=\overline{A}$. Consider the denominator ideal
$$ I=\{ b\in B \mid bf\in B\}$$
of $f$. I claim that $I\cap A$ is not contained in $q$. Admitting this, let $s\in I\cap A\setminus q$, then $sf\in B$ and $f$ is integral over $A_q$.

Now we prove the claim. Suppose that $I\cap A\subseteq q$. Then, geometrically, $q\in V(I\cap A)\subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(A)$. As $A/(I\cap A)\to B/I$ is injective and integral, $\mathrm{Spec}(B/I)\to \mathrm{Spec}(A/(I\cap A))$ is surjective. Identify $V(I)$ with $\mathrm{Spec}(B/I)$, this implies that there exists $p\in V(I)$ such that $p\cap A=q$. So $p$ is a prime ideal of $B$ lying over $q$ and containing $I$. This contradicts the hypothesis $f\in B_p$.

Comment: $\def\frq{\mathfrak{q}}
\def\frp{\mathfrak{p}}$This result is a corollary of the following result (Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, Ch. V, § 2, no. 1, Proposition 2): Let $h:A\to B$ be an integral ring homomorphism, $\frq$ a prime ideal of $A$, $(\frp_i)_{i\in I}$ the family of all prime ideals of $B$ lying above $\frq$ and $S=\bigcap_{i\in I}B-\frp_i$; then $B_\frq=S^{-1}B$. Plus the following observation: if $B$ is some integral domain and for $i\in I$, $S_i\subset B$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $B$, then $(\bigcap S_i)^{-1}B=\bigcap S_i^{-1}B$ as subrings of $Q(B)$.

Comment: To prove $(\bigcap S_i)^{-1}B=\bigcap S_i^{-1}B$, we note that $\subset$ is easy. Conversely, suppose $b/s\in Q(B)$ is not in $(\bigcap S_i)^{-1}B$. Then $s\not\in\bigcap S_i$, whence $s\not\in S_i$, for some $i$. Thus, $b/s\not\in S_i^{-1}B$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\dim A=1$. One can assume that $A$ is a local Noetherian domain with maximal ideal $m$ and have to prove that $\overline{A}=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\overline{A}_{P_i}$, where $P_1,\dots,P_n$ are all the prime ideals of $\overline{A}$ lying over $m$. (There are only finitely many primes in $\overline{A}$ lying over $m$ because $\overline{A}$ is Dedekind!) Now one can use the well known fact that an integral domain (in our case $\overline{A}$) is the intersection of all its localizations at maximal ideals. Note that a prime ideal $P$ of $\overline{A}$ is lying over $m$ or over $(0)$. The prime ideals $P$ lying over $(0)$ give "large" localizations, i.e. $\overline{A}_P=K$ when $P\cap A=(0)$, where $K$ is the field of fractions of $A$. In particular these primes can be removed from the intersection finally remaining only the primes $P$ lying over $m$.